# ruby error during blog migration from wordpress to jekyll

Tags: ruby, wordpress, migration, jekyll

I'm trying to migrate my blog from wordpress to jekyll.

I'm following the [Jekyll migration documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/migrations/#using_wordpress_mysql_server_connection). However when I run:

```
$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/jekyll-import/wordpress";
    JekyllImport::WordPress.process({:host => "127.0.0.1", :dbname => "database", :user => "user", :pass => "pass"})'
```

(replacing host, dname, user and pass with the correct arguments).

I get the following message back:

```
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting =>
...ort::WordPress.process({:host =, :dbname =, :user =, :pass =
...                               ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm on windows and ruby 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely using the `:host => 'x'` notation and not `:host = 'x'`? (The error message suggests the latter.) The arrow notation is important.

You can use the alternate hash notation to remove all doubt:

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/jekyll-import/wordpress"; JekyllImport::WordPress.process({host: "127.0.0.1", dbname: "database", user: "user", pass: "pass"})'
```

Comment: I still think I had the syntax correctly. Anyway the `host: "127.0.0.1"` syntax worked (I got another error, but that's another story).